# Animating child back to original position

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am using the `animate()` method to send my TextView to the bottom-most-right of the layout using the following code:

```
move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int xValue = container.getWidth() - myView.getWidth();
                int yValue = container.getHeight() - myView.getHeight();
                myView.animate().x(xValue).y(yValue);
            }
        });
```

This does the trick but I am sort of lost on restoring the element back to its original position. I did try the following, but it didn't work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button fadeIn, fadeOut, move, moveBack;
    TextView myView;
    LinearLayout container;
    float originalX , originalY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fadeIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fadeIn);
        fadeOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fadeOut);
        move = (Button)findViewById(R.id.move);
        moveBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.moveBack);
        myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
        originalX = myView.getX();
        originalY = myView.getY();
        Log.i("X and Y", ""+originalX+" "+originalY);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        fadeIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myView.animate().alpha(1);
            }
        });
        fadeOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myView.animate().alpha(0);
            }
        });
        move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int xValue = container.getWidth() - myView.getWidth();
                int yValue = container.getHeight() - myView.getHeight();
                myView.animate().x(xValue).y(yValue);
            }
        });
        moveBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myView.animate().x(originalX).y(originalY);;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

The following gives me with the `0,0` position on `X and Y`. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [TranslateAnimations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html). Something like.-

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(originalX, xValue, originalY, yValue);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
myView.startAnimation(anim);
```

And revert the values to restore the original position.-

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(xValue, originalX, yValue, originalY);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
myView.startAnimation(anim);
```